# GCP Query Insight for Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, cloud

A couple of GCP Postgres Query Insight questions:

1. It seems that I have to enable Query Insight every time I enter the tool from GCP console.  Is that normal?  I would expect to enable it only once for a PG server.
2. How can I eliminate internal postgres queries to be shown in the query window in Query Insight initial page?  I would like to avoid any internal postgres query - ie.  "FROM pg_" in it.  There's an option to filter queries but not able to figure it out easily.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#1 above, enabling QueryInsight at the server level will resolve that issue via GCP console.  However, I had learned that we had configuration connector installed on that postgres server which undid the enabling of queryInsight via the GCP console.

#2 above - as per google support that ability for NOT filtering is not available.